# VC++ programmatically add excel OLEObject?

Tags: visual-c++, excel-interop, createoleobject

I'm having trouble adding an OLEObject to an excel worksheet in VC++ using Interop libraries.
Compiler is VC++ 2010 express.
Interop libraries are for Office 2007.

Here's the declaration:

```
#define XL Microsfot::Office::Interop::Excel
...
XL::Application^ xlApp;
XL::Workbook^ xlWb;
XL::Worksheet^ xlWs;
```

Here's the code to control excel:

```
xlApp = gcnew XL::ApplicationClass();
xlWb = xlApp->Workbooks->Add(Type::Missing);
xlWs = safe_cast<XL::Worksheet^>(xlApp->ActiveSheet);

xlApp->Visible = true;

xlWs->Cells[1, 1] = "OMG I can put stuff in cells no problem";

//this line generates an error C2227: left of '->Add' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
xlWs->OLEObjects->Add("somefile.someext", false, false);
```

I did a macro recording in excel to add an OLEObject and this is the VB code it generates:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:="C:\somefile.someext", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False).Select
```

So there is an Add method to OLEObjects in VB but not in C++?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
XL::OLEObjects^ xlObjs = safe_cast<XL::OLEObjects^>(xlWs->OLEObjects(Type::Missing));
xlObjs->Add(Type::Missing, "somefile.someext", false, false, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, Type::Missing, 0, 0, 20, 20);
```